# getByRole not able to fetch h6 in React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I am trying to catch a heading `h6` of one of my page that loads after an API call. As it's asynchronous, I have wrapped it inside `waitFor`. RTL gives the error `TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find role="heading"` even when I can see `h6` in the DOM printed just after the error. Following is the test:

```
test("ABC test", async () => {
  render(<DetailsPage />);
  await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByRole('heading')).toBeTruthy());
});
```

This is the screengrab of the RTL console:

[image]

What am I missing?

PS: I am sure that the test finishes after the DOM has been updated with the Summary heading because the DOM error is printed on the console before the jest test summary.

Comment: Try using `const { getByRole } = render(<DetailsPage />);` and `getByRole('heading')` (instead of `screen.getByRole('heading')`)

Comment: As per the recommendation by Kent, I prefer using `screen`.
https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#not-using-screen

Comment: Got it but can you please check if there is any different or not on the result?

Comment: Checking just the test, everything looks good (You don't even have to use `waitFor`). Would be good if you add your `DetailsPage ` component code.

Comment: You need to provide the code of `DetailsPage` component.